# mssql_connect will not connect different DB on same SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, database

```
$conn_161 = "192.168.0.161";  //local serwer adress
$user_161 = "ME";
$pass_161 = "what_is_the_password?";
$connect_161 = mssql_connect($conn_161,$user_161,$pass_161);
mssql_select_db ( 'DUKENUKEN3D' , $connect_161 );

//as requested - 1st DB connection and 1st query
$q_duke = "select * from DUKE /*DB1*/";
$r_duke = mssql_query($q_wartownik,$connect_161); //result

$connect_different_db = mssql_connect($conn_161,$user_161,$pass_161);
mssql_select_db ( 'BIGMAN' , $connect_different_db );

//second db and query
$q_bigman = "select * from BIGPEOPLE /*DB2*/";
$r_bigman = mssql_query($q_bigman,$connect_different_db ); //result
```

**Error:**

> Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: Invalid object name 'DUKE'.

Yes I know `mssql_select_db` is old, but I need to use it in this project. As you see I try to connect to same server but select 2 different DB at the same time, and run queries in the same php page (to connect data from 2 different DB). It seems it is not valiable? I even tried to run `mssql_select_db` just before doing the query to second DB, and then changing it back to first DB.

I understand this is limitation of the library (I will run all queries from LAST selected DB).

Is there a workaroud? Because all I got is to create page inside invisible iframe and there run php page with different db connection - far from good solution.

Comment: You need to show us the query you are making because the error is related to the query, not the selection of the database or the database connection. I base this on the warning saying the mssql_query() function was used.

Comment: _Side note:_ There's no reason to quote variables when passing them as function arguments. Instead of:  `mssql_connect("$conn_161", ...)`, just do `mssql_connect($conn_161, ...etc)`

Comment: Seems like the error is pretty clear here. The object `TABLE_NAME` exists in  the database where you connect (query) work, but it doesn't exist in the other database, thus your query fails.

Comment: I hae updated the answear. Yes that is the point - I don't have TABLE_NAME (DUKE after edit) in the second database - but I dont control the database - I just need to take data from both DB it and I dont know how since mssql_select_db will now work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect that this will work the same as it would if you were running this in a SQL environment directly (e.g. you can try it in SSMS or from the command line).

You can specify the database name when you reference the table in the query: e.g.

```
select * from db1.dbo.DUKE
```

This is standard SQL Server behaviour whenever you want to refer to an object which is outside the context of the current database.

Comment: Thanx. Looks promissing. I'm not at work right now - I will try this and accept the answear when I can.

Comment: You sir are absolutelly right! Didn't think of that. This is correct syntax in my case: `select * from [DUKENUKEN3D].[dbo].[zmiany] //dbo means database owner` I gues

Comment: Yes, dbo means database owner. It denotes the schema within the database which the table belongs to. Glad it helped you.